# how to add external drawables to android gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an android project (using AndroidStudio/gradle) laid out something like this:

```
./project/app/src/main/res/
./project/art_assets/<category>/drawables/*.png
```

In a given layout XML I want to refer to a graphic resource for an ImageButton like this:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/asdf"
    android:src="@drawable/external_graphic_file" />
```

I have added the following sourceSets block in the app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDir('../art_assets/category/drawables')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still get an error from the build that it cannot find a resource for @drawable/external_graphic_file and evidence of failure from aapt.

How do I properly reference an external set of resources in the gradle build?  And by 'external' I mean, "outside the ./app/ directory tree, but within the same project directory."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work just fine.  I could edit my question to make it right, but then it wouldn't be much of a question anymore.

The only thing wrong is/was the .png files needed to reside in `drawable-*dpi/` directories under the `drawables` dir.  Changing the `./art_assets/` tree as follows is all that is necessary:

```
./project/art_assets/<category>/drawables/drawable-xhdpi/*.png
```

Note the additional `drawable-xhdpi` directory layer.